# Почему в слове превосходить корень "превосход", а не "ход"?

Tags: этимология, грамматика, словообразование, корень-слова, историческая-грамматика

Почему в слове превосходить корень "превосход", а не "ход"? Получается, что даже восходить и превосходить - не являются однокоренными словами, хотя их смысл схож межу собой

Answer (score 1):

**[Разбор по составу](https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C):** ***вос/ход/и/ть, превосход/и/ть.***

Корень ***ХОД*** выделяется в глаголе "восходить", а в глаголе "превосходить" выделяется корень ***ПРЕВОСХОД***. Его можно назвать словообразовательным формантом, который включает корень ***ХОД*** и две приставки.

**Почему так?** По толковому словарю мы видим, что слово ***превосходить*** по семантике не соответствует значению корня ***ХОД***, связанному с **перемещением**.  А новый **оттенок значения** придают корню две приставки: ***ВОЗ/ВОС*** и ***ПРЕ*** (движение вверх и превосходство).

Поэтому нужно обязательно **проверять свое  решение** по **словообразовательному** словарю Тихонова (или другому словарю, который рекомендован вашим педагогом в школе), а также по учебным материалам в Сети.  Семантику слова нужно уточнить в **толковом** словаре.

Принципы морфемного членения можно посмотреть в книге Литневской на Грамоте.ру или **[здесь](https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p19).**

```
Формально-структурному подходу противопоставлен 
подход формально-смысловой (формально- 
семантический). Главная установка данного подхода и 
алгоритм морфемного разбора выходят из трудов Г. О. 
Винокура и состоят в неразрывности морфемного 
членения и словообразовательного разбора. О том, что 
этот подход является целесообразным и даже 
единственно возможным, писали многие учёные и 
методисты на протяжении многих десятилетий.
```

**Словари**

**ХОДИТЬ,** хожу, ходишь; нсв. 1. Обладать способностью, быть в состоянии двигаться, ступая ногами, делая шаги (о человеке, животном). Ребёнок начал х. в десять месяцев. Ваш сын уже ходит? 2. Перемещаться, ступая ногами, делая шаги в разных направлениях или в разное время (о человеке, животном). Больному разрешили х. Х. по парку, по тротуару. Х. вдоль набережной, аллеи. Х. через огороды, чёрный ход.

**ПРЕВЗОЙТИ,** -взойду, -взойдёшь; превзошёл, -шла, -шло; превзошедший; превзойдённый; -дён, -дена, -дено; превзойдя и превзошедши; св. **1. кого-что, чем, в чём, по чему. Обнаружить превосходство** над кем-, чем-л. в каком-л. отношении. П. всех силою. П. соперника. П. что-л. числом, размером. П. кого-л. по численности. П. сверстников в ловкости. П. собеседника по широте взглядов. Новый сорт сливы, вероятно, превзойдёт прочие по морозоустойчивости. 2. что. Оказаться больше чего-л.; превысить.

Comment: _**«Поэтому нужно обязательно проверять свое решение по словообразовательному словарю Тихонова…»**_ === А почему именно по словарю Тихонова, а не, к примеру, по словарям Панова и Текучева, Потихи, Ефремовой, Морковкина и др.? Кстати, перечисленные мной авторы словарей в слове «превосходить» выделяют корень  **«ход»**. 

Comment: Словарик учитель подберет (например, в соответствии с учебным комплексом).

Comment: _**«Словарик учитель подберет (например, в соответствии с учебным комплексом).**_ === Ну так если учитель подберёт не тихоновский словарь, а какого-либо из перечисленных мной выше авторов, корнем в слове _**превосходить**_ окажется совсем не «превосход», как у Тихонова и в Вашем ответе, а _**«ход»**_!  

Comment: Тогда надо менять школу)  Это учебный комплекс 2, упрощенная программа обучения. Кстати, что там у нас с единым образовательным стандартом? А то утомляют эти поиски подходящего словаря. Литневская считает формально-семантический разбор наиболее целесообразным. Морфемно-орфографический словарь А.Н. Тихонова — один из самых востребованных словарей в школьной практике изучения русского языка.
Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/tikhonov  А простой народ недоволен. Тогда надо изучать в школе два метода разбора (структурный и семантический) и несколько словарей, чтобы  понятнее было.

Comment: Вот тогда все будут довольны)  У нас фонетику и словообразование начинают изучать в начальной школе,  а за 10 лет обучения ничего не меняется, уровень знаний все тот же.  Это нормально?